# JQuery plugin method is not getting called after re loading partial view using jquery in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

Have a side bar in a view. When I click an item, corresponding view is loaded as partial view to my main view. In my partial view I use jquery plugin (fixedHeaderTable) to render a table. When I load my view, first side menu item view is loaded by default. This works fine . But if I navigate to another side menu and the click the first side menu item , my view gets rendered but it says it cant accesses the jquery plugin method.

My Main view where I load the partial view . When I inspect the page from chrome, I could see that the jquery plugin is loaded.

```
@model App.Core.DataAccess.ViewModel.TimeTrackerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function onSideMenuClick(selectedItem) {
        if (selectedItem.id === 'timetracker') {
            $.get("@Url.Action("TimeTracker", "Reports")", function (data) {
                $('#divProduct').html(data);
            });
            $('#TimeTracker').fixedHeaderTable({
                altClass: 'odd',
                fixedColumns: 1,
                autoResize: true,
                create: function () {
                    $(".fht-fixed-body>.fht-tbody").niceScroll({ styler: "fb", cursorcolor: "#7e7d7d" });
                }
            });
        }
        else if (selectedItem.id === 'tabPatientFlowSummary') {
            $.get("@Url.Action("PatientFlowSummary", "Reports")", function (data) {
                $('#divProduct').html(data);
            });
            $('#PatientFlowSummary').fixedHeaderTable('destroy');
            $('#PatientFlowSummary').fixedHeaderTable({
                altClass: 'odd',
                fixedColumns: 1,
                autoResize: true
            });
        }
        else if (selectedItem.id === 'tabProductionCollectionSummary') {
            $.get("@Url.Action("Index", "ProductionCollectionSummary")", function (data) {
                $('#divProduct').html(data);
            });
        }
        else if (selectedItem.id === 'tabInpurReport') {
            $.get("@Url.Action("DailyCollection", "Reports")", function (data) {
                $('#divProduct').html(data);
            });
        }
        else if (selectedItem.id === 'tabMidYearReport') {
            $.get("@Url.Action("MidYearReport", "Reports")", function (data) {
                $('#divProduct').html(data);
            });
        }
        else {
            $.get("@Url.Action("AnnualReport", "Reports")", function (data) {
                $('#divProduct').html(data);
            });
        }
    }
  </script>
@section SideBar{
    <section class="sidebar">
        <a href="#" id="sidebarToggle">Sidebar Toggle</a>
        <div class="sidebar-content">
            <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="onSideMenuClick(this);" id="timetracker" class="active" ><i class="icon-patient_flow_summary"></i>Time Tracker</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="onSideMenuClick(this);" id="tabPatientFlowSummary" ><i class="icon-patient_flow_summary"></i>Patient Flow Summary </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="onSideMenuClick(this);" id="tabProductionCollectionSummary" >Production Collection Summary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="onSideMenuClick(this);" id="tabInpurReport"><i class="icon-daily-collection"></i>Daily Collection </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="onSideMenuClick(this);" id="tabMidYearReport"><i class="icon-mid_year_report" ></i>Mid Year Report </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="onSideMenuClick(this);" id="tabAnnualReport"><i class="icon-annual_report"></i>Annual Report</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</section>
}
<div id="divProduct" class="main-content-area-wap width-sidebar clearfix">@Html.Action("TimeTracker","Reports")</div>
```

My controls is as shown

```
public PartialViewResult TimeTracker() 
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        if (timetrackerViewModel == null)
        {
            timetrackerViewModel = new TimeTrackerViewModel();
        }
        timetrackerViewModel.lstHrsAval = new List<decimal>();
        timetrackerViewModel.HoursWorked = new List<decimal>();
        timetrackerViewModel.NoOfVisits = new List<decimal>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            timetrackerViewModel.lstHrsAval.Add(i);
            timetrackerViewModel.HoursWorked.Add(i);
            timetrackerViewModel.NoOfVisits.Add(i);
        }
        return PartialView("_TimeTrackerPartial", timetrackerViewModel);
    }
```

I am loading all my scripts files,jquery, jquery plugins in my _layout View .Am i doing something wrong .

Comment: most likely one of your views is loading another copy of jquery.

Comment: @KevinB you mean to say that in other view I am loading jquery again ?

Comment: I don't see where you are doing it, but that's what the symptoms suggest. if jQuery is still there, but your plugin is no longer there, that typically means a new copy of jquery was included and it overwrote the previous.

Comment: @KevinB I can see jquery and my plugin loaded when i use chrome developer tool.

Comment: right, but can you see jquery twice, after you refresh the view?